# Error with npm install on mozjpeg, permission denied?

Tags: linux, npm, cpanel, centos7, node-modules

I am running `npm install` and I get the following error:

```
> mozjpeg@5.0.0 postinstall /home/MyUser/public_html/node_modules/mozjpeg
> node lib/install.js

  ⚠ The `/home/MyUser/public_html/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg` binary doesn't seem to work correctly
  ⚠ mozjpeg pre-build test failed
  ℹ compiling from source
  ✖ Error: autoreconf -fiv && ./configure --disable-shared --disable-dependency-tracking --with-jpeg8  --prefix="/home/MyUser/public_html/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor" --bindir="/home/MyUser/public_html/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor" --libdir="/home/MyUser/public_html/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor" && make -j4 && make install -j4
Command failed: ./configure --disable-shared --disable-dependency-tracking --with-jpeg8  --prefix="/home/MyUser/public_html/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor" --bindir="/home/MyUser/public_html/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor" --libdir="/home/MyUser/public_html/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor"
/bin/sh: ./configure: Permission denied

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:199:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:351:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:497:12)

> optipng-bin@3.1.4 postinstall /home/MyUser/public_html/node_modules/optipng-bin
> node lib/install.js

  ✔ optipng pre-build test passed successfully

> pngquant-bin@4.0.0 postinstall /home/MyUser/public_html/node_modules/pngquant-bin
> node lib/install.js

  ⚠ The `/home/MyUser/public_html/node_modules/pngquant-bin/vendor/pngquant` binary doesn't seem to work correctly
  ⚠ pngquant pre-build test failed
  ℹ compiling from source
  ✔ pngquant pre-build test passed successfully
  ✖ Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed
    at Promise.all.then.arr (/home/MyUser/public_html/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-build/node_modules/execa/index.js:231:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

This seems like lack of permissions, but I don't understand why. If I run the same command as root, everything works fine. What am I lacking permissions for, and how can I fix that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem here on xubuntu 17.10, what I did was install libpng-dev
`sudo apt-get install libpng-dev` then run again `npm install`. This solved my problem

Comment: that did not fix my issue. libpng-dev is installed, but I have to run npm as root otherwise I am not able to compile. I guess this is some security restriction on the server.